# Notification function in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, notifications, laravel-8

I want to develop a notification in my dashboard in Laravel that notifies the user if something has been updated. Such as a new upload or a new event in a calendar. How can I accomplish this? The following are my controllers and routes.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Hash;
use App\Models\{
    Fileupload,
    User
};
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Datables;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Dashboard";
        $isCurrent = "dashboard";

        return view('dashboard.index', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Profile";
        $isCurrent = "Profile";
        $users = User::all();

        $fileuploads = Fileupload::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->limit(3)
            ->latest()
            ->get();

        return view('dashboard.profile', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent,
            'users' => $users,
            'fileuploads' => $fileuploads,
        ]);
    }

    public function editProfile()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Profile Edit";
        $isCurrent = "prodile edit";

        $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();

        return view('dashboard.profile-edit', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent,
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();

        $user->name = $request->get('name');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $user->contact_no = $request->get('contact_no');
        $user->bdate = $request->get('bdate');

        $user->profile_image = $request->file('profile_image') ? Storage::disk('public')->put('images', $request->profile_image) : $user->profile_image;

        $user->save();

        return redirect(route('dashboard.profile'));
    }

    public function directory()
    {
       $dashboardTitle = "Directory";
    $isCurrent = "Directory";
    $users = User::all();
    return view('dashboard.directory', [
        'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
        'isCurrent' => $isCurrent,
        'users' => $users
    ]);

    
    }
    public function journal()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Journal";
        $isCurrent = "Journal";
        return view('dashboard.journal', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function files()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Files";
        $isCurrent = "Files";
        return view('dashboard.files', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }

    public function calendar()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Calendar";
        $isCurrent = "calenadr";

        return view('dashboard.calendar', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    
    public function delete(){
      $user = Auth::user();
        Auth::logout();
        
    
        if ($user->delete()) {
    
             return redirect(route('home.index'));
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

And here is for the file uploads.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Models\Fileupload;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class FileuploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Files";
        $isCurrent = "Files";
        return view('dashboard.files', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function files(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('uploadedfile');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = time(). '.' .$filename;
    
        $path = Storage::disk('docs')
            ->putFileAs(
                "/" . Auth::user()->id,
                $file,
                $filename
            );
    
        Fileupload::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'filename' => $path
        ]);

        return redirect(route('dashboard.profile'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
      
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

the calendar

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function getEvents()
    {
        return Event::find(1);
    }

    public function addEvent(Request $request)
    {
        $event = Event::find(1);
        $event->events = $request->get('events');
        $event->save();

        return $event;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the basic Notification trait from Laravel. If the requirements not need emails notification use the database via, and in the models listen for created or updated model hooks. This need to be defined by your requirements and the Laravel resources for this